# Assistance with proof for the existence of an inverse of a linear transformation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Suppose $S$ is a continuous linear transformation from a normed space $X$ onto a normed space $Y$ satisfying $||Sx||\geq b||x||$ for some $b>0$ and all $x\in X$. I want to show that $S^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ exists and is continuous.

I want to show that S is both injective and surjective. Injectivity I can do: Suppose $Sx_1=Sx_2$. Then, $$0=||Sx_1-Sx_2||=||S(x_1-x_2)||\geq b||x_1-x_2||,$$

which imples that $||x_1-x_2||=0$ since $b>0$. Thus $x_1=x_2$.

However, I am struggling with my proof for injectivity. Can someone provide me with a hint for how to prove this?

Thanks

Comment: $S$ does not need to be surjective at all; consider $x \mapsto (x,0): \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$, each equipped with the standard norm. This satisfies your condition for $b = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you copied the question verbatim, when it says "onto" $Y $ it is telling you that it is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\neq0$, then $||x||>0$. so $||Sx||\geq b||x||>0$. Hence $Sx\neq0~\forall x\neq0$. Hence $S$ is invertible.

Comment: Can you explain why this means S is invertible? Thank you